# LinearLayout sets a background, but not for all children

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to do this efect:

[image]

The last linear layout contains a circle in an ImageView and the background is set from the center to the end, how can I do this?

Using a shape doesn't work fine..

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a stretched image as background, or have multiple layers of views.
In the latter way you can have a RelativeLayout, a background view, and the foreground view:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="48dp">
  <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#808080" />
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    text="This is the foreground" />
</RelativeLayout>
```